# '/Applications/PostgreSQL 16/pg_restore' file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog

Tags: postgresql

My next step was to locate the 'bin' folder in the PostgreSQL folder and set it to my current folder in PGadmin4. I located the folder and was unable to locate the 'bin' file needed to set the binary path. I noticed on the tutorials that they were PC users, I am a MAC user, does this make a difference?

Tried downloading two earlier versions of the PostgreSQL15 and 14.  No bin file is present in the other two versions.

Comment: Without any information about how and where you installed PostgreSQL, this is my path to the bin-directory: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/bin`. As you can see, I use Postgres.app for all local installations.